# Why is variable not being reset each time function is called

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I was reading [Professor Frisby's Mostly adequate guide to functional programming](http://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch3.html) and I came across this code example shown below.  I don't understand why cache is not reset to {} each time squareNumber is called.

```
var memoize = function(f){
    var cache = {}; // why is this not reset each time squareNumber is called?

    return function() {
        var arg_str = JSON.stringify(arguments);
        cache[arg_str] = cache[arg_str]|| f.apply(f, arguments);
        return cache[arg_str];
    };
}

var squareNumber = memoize(function(x){ return x*x; });
squareNumber(4);
//=> 16
squareNumber(4); // returns cache for input 4
//=> 16
squareNumber(5);
//=> 25
squareNumber(5); // returns cache for input 5
//=> 25
```

One theory I have is that since memoize is a global variable the cache variable is not reset every time it is called.  But I can't seem to find a good solution.

Comment: Why do you think it *would* be reset? The function that `memoize` returns doesn't ever change the value of `cache`, so what would change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute:

```
var squareNumber = memoize(function(x){ return x*x; });
```

The `cache` variable inside of `memoize()` is initialized and a reference to the inner function is returned and assigned to `squareNumber`.  That inner function has a reference to that `cache` object and each time it is called when you do `squareNumber(x)`, that inner function continues to have a reference to that same original `cache` variable.

This is actually the intended behavior of this design pattern so the cache can persist from one call to the next.

If you want a fresh copy of the cache, then you must call `memoize()` again to start over with a fresh cache and fresh inner function that has a reference to the new `cache` variable.

FYI, this is called a closure because though `memoize()` has run and completed, the reference to the inner function that was returned from executing `memoize()` has references to the local variables of `memoize()` so those local variables are not garbage collected by the JS interpreter, even though `memoize()` has long since finished executing.  This is called a closure.

Answer (score 5):

Because the function `memoize` is only being called once. `memoize(function(x){ return x*x; })` simply gives the return value, which happens to be a function.